How To Insert query in Flutter with PostgreSQL new package? postgres: ^3.2.1
How To Insert query in Flutter with PostgreSQL new package? postgres: ^3.2.1
all the other documentation are old, deprecated and not working anymore, could you someone please help on this..?
How to insert data to table.?
How to delete data in table.?
How to update data to table.?
Even ChatGPT is giving old methods that is not working anymore.
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

Future<void> insertUser() async {
  // Configure the database connection
  final connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
    'your_host', // e.g., 'localhost' or 'your_db_host'
    5432, // Port number, usually 5432 for PostgreSQL
    'your_database_name',
    username: 'your_username',
    password: 'your_password',
  );

  // Open the connection
  await connection.open();

  // Execute the insert statement
  await connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_id) VALUES (@userName, @userId)',
    substitutionValues: {
      'userName': 'ismail',
      'userId': 1001,
    },
  );

  // Close the connection
  await connection.close();
}

void main() async {
  await insertUser();
  print("User inserted");
}

For example, here PosgresqlConnection, Connection.Query, SubtitutionValue etc, all are not used anymore and deprecated, this was the sample code to perform insert before.

See line 44 of https://github.com/isoos/postgresql-dart/blob/master/example/example.dart

import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

class Example {
  late final Connection _conn;
  static final Endpoint _endpoint = Endpoint(
    host: 'your_host', // e.g., 'localhost' or 'your_db_host',
    database: 'your_database_name',
    username: 'your_username',
    password: 'your_password',
  );

 static const ConnectionSettings _connectionSettings =
 ConnectionSettings(sslMode: SslMode.disable);

 Future<void> insertUser(String userName, int userId) async {
   try {
     _conn = await Connection.open(_endpoint, settings: 
     _connectionSettings);
     await _conn.execute(
      'INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_id) VALUES ($userName, $userId)');
   } catch (e) {
      print('Error: ${e.toString()}');
   } finally {
     _conn.close();
   }
  }
 }

void main() async {
  await Example().insertUser('ismail', 1001);
  print("User inserted");
}

I think something like this should work. The pub.dev has some more examples: https://pub.dev/packages/postgres/example
